# XAMPP + wordpress - run a local secure intranet server on W10

Tags: windows, networking, security

I discovered XAMPP recently, and was intrigued by how easy it is to have a server up and running on Windows.
I also installed Wordpress on it, and it was a breeze; in few steps I have my wordpress blog site, running on localhost.

Although I am not sure about the implications for security: I can access the IP of the machine running XAMPP and have a local intranet, so anyone in my small office can basically access to it, after I created their local usernames.

What should I do to make the site secure? I am not planning to open this to the outside internet; I just want to run it on my local network (I have 5 computers at my office; and 1 router, which is the only gateway to the internet connection; basically a super simple setup. For Wifi connection I have whitelisted only the computer at the office, so no other computer can access to it; while for wired connection I have just 10 IP allocated, and MAC address of the various machines saved in the router).